# why does mutiset don't act like set

Tags: c++, multiset

Why is multiset a set while a set can only contains only different elements, while multiset can contain the same elements? It could of just be called `sortedArray` or `sortedList`. Even if it just wants a sorted "collections", why is it a set?

Comment: Because computer scientists like to abuse mathematical terminology. Another example is calling % the modulus operator.

Comment: Ask the people who proposed it to the C++ standards committee.

Comment: [Compare. Search, insertion, and removal operations have logarithmic complexity.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset), you dont get that from a `sortedArray`

Comment: Perhaps it's because its implementation will probably have to be very similar to that of a `set` so it's seen from that perspective rather than from the perspective of the users. Like @idclev463035818 mentioned, it has some requirements that are the same as those of a `set`.

Comment: Multiset is not a set, it is multiset, it models mathematical concept of multiset: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset.

Comment: ... and also, why call it `set` when it should probably have been `ordered_set` and `unordered_set` should have been called `set`. @ks1322 That looks like it should be an answer.

Comment: FWIW, `sortedArray` and `sortedList` don't convey the same guarantees.  An array has contiguous storage which a multiset does not and while a list can be binary searched through, you still have linear time since you can't randomly access the nodes in the list.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "why is multiset a set?" part of the question? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is multiset a set

In mathematics there are two distinct concept of [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) and [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). Standard library has two containers that model these concepts: `std::set` and `std::multiset`. These concepts are not the same and therefore container names are also different because they model different mathematical concepts.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is multiset a set [...]

It's not. The word "set" does appear in "multiset", but that does not make a multiset a set. A multiset is a generalization of a set, not necessarily itself a set. This linguistic setup is similar to a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph), which is a generalization of a graph but not necessarily a graph, and to a [hyperplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane), which is a generalization of a plane but not necessarily a plane.

A less mathematical example would be [penultimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penultimate), which is not "ultimate", or any other word with a prefix that changes the meaning of the root.

Perhaps "butterfly" and "dragonfly" would be apropos examples. Neither is a fly, despite the word "fly" appearing in both names. (For that matter, neither is buttery or draconic.) Sometimes a name is just a name.